# SQL Exists returning errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

So I have the following query:

```
select *
from ft, pn
where exists (ft.vendnm like '%rocha%' and pn.fno = ft.fno);
```

Where I only want the results that respect the conditions inside parenthesis.
What SQL Server tells me is:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

And I'm not getting what's wrong with this.

The whole code for context:

```
select 
x.Num,
x.Cliente,
x.Zona,
sum(x.valor_1) as Valor_1,
sum(x.valor_2) as Valor_2,
x.Vendnm,
'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' as Data1,
'2021-12-31 00:00:00.000' as Data2,
'2022-01-01 00:00:00.000' as Data3,
'2022-12-31 00:00:00.000' as Data4,
(select sum(pn.etiliquido) from pn where pn.vendedor in (3) and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-12-31 00:00:00.000')) as VT1,
(select sum(pn.etiliquido) from pn where pn.vendedor in (3) and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-12-31 00:00:00.000')) as VT2,


isnull(
round((((select sum(pn.etiliquido) from pn where pn.no in (select no from cl where cl.vendedor = 3) and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-12-31 00:00:00.000') AND PN.REF NOT IN ('DESC. FINANCEIRO','PORTES','DESP.BANCARIAS','COL. COM.','VENDA VIAT CI','RESP.TRANSPORTE','RECIGLAGEM','MARK. CONT. 2013','RAPPEL13','JUROS','VENDA VIAT SI','CREDITO SRCM','RAPPEL14','FEIRAS','MARK. CONT. 2014','MARK. CONT. 2015','RAPPEL15','RAPPEL16','MARK. CONT. 2016','RAPPEL17','MARK. CONT. 2017','RAPPEL18','MARK. CONT. 2018','RAPPEL19','MARK. CONT. 2019','MARK. CONT. 2020','RAPPEL20','MARK. CONT. 2021','RAPPEL21','MARK. CONT. 2022','RAPPEL22') and  pn.usr1 not in ('12-DAS','13-DIDO','19-GIOTTO','19-GIOTTO BE-BÈ','10-ADIGRAF','27-OMYACOLOR','28-PONGO', '18-FILA', '36-TRATTO','48 - LYRA'))
-
(select sum(pn.etiliquido) from pn where pn.no in (select no from cl where cl.vendedor = 3) and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-12-31 00:00:00.000') AND PN.REF NOT IN ('DESC. FINANCEIRO','PORTES','DESP.BANCARIAS','COL. COM.','VENDA VIAT CI','RESP.TRANSPORTE','RECIGLAGEM','MARK. CONT. 2013','RAPPEL13','JUROS','VENDA VIAT SI','CREDITO SRCM','RAPPEL14','FEIRAS','MARK. CONT. 2014','MARK. CONT. 2015','RAPPEL15','RAPPEL16','MARK. CONT. 2016','RAPPEL17','MARK. CONT. 2017','RAPPEL18','MARK. CONT. 2018','RAPPEL19','MARK. CONT. 2019','MARK. CONT. 2020','RAPPEL20','MARK. CONT. 2021','RAPPEL21','MARK. CONT. 2022','RAPPEL22') and  pn.usr1 not in ('12-DAS','13-DIDO','19-GIOTTO','19-GIOTTO BE-BÈ','10-ADIGRAF','27-OMYACOLOR','28-PONGO', '18-FILA', '36-TRATTO','48 - LYRA'))))*100,2),0) as Diftotal,


isnull(
round((((select sum(pn.etiliquido) from pn where pn.no in (select no from cl where cl.vendedor = 3) and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-12-31 00:00:00.000') AND PN.REF NOT IN ('DESC. FINANCEIRO','PORTES','DESP.BANCARIAS','COL. COM.','VENDA VIAT CI','RESP.TRANSPORTE','RECIGLAGEM','MARK. CONT. 2013','RAPPEL13','JUROS','VENDA VIAT SI','CREDITO SRCM','RAPPEL14','FEIRAS','MARK. CONT. 2014','MARK. CONT. 2015','RAPPEL15','RAPPEL16','MARK. CONT. 2016','RAPPEL17','MARK. CONT. 2017','RAPPEL18','MARK. CONT. 2018','RAPPEL19','MARK. CONT. 2019','MARK. CONT. 2020','RAPPEL20','MARK. CONT. 2021','RAPPEL21','MARK. CONT. 2022','RAPPEL22') and  pn.usr1 not in ('12-DAS','13-DIDO','19-GIOTTO','19-GIOTTO BE-BÈ','10-ADIGRAF','27-OMYACOLOR','28-PONGO', '18-FILA', '36-TRATTO','48 - LYRA'))
-
(select sum(pn.etiliquido) from pn where pn.no in (select no from cl where cl.vendedor = 3) and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-12-31 00:00:00.000') AND PN.REF NOT IN ('DESC. FINANCEIRO','PORTES','DESP.BANCARIAS','COL. COM.','VENDA VIAT CI','RESP.TRANSPORTE','RECIGLAGEM','MARK. CONT. 2013','RAPPEL13','JUROS','VENDA VIAT SI','CREDITO SRCM','RAPPEL14','FEIRAS','MARK. CONT. 2014','MARK. CONT. 2015','RAPPEL15','RAPPEL16','MARK. CONT. 2016','RAPPEL17','MARK. CONT. 2017','RAPPEL18','MARK. CONT. 2018','RAPPEL19','MARK. CONT. 2019','MARK. CONT. 2020','RAPPEL20','MARK. CONT. 2021','RAPPEL21','MARK. CONT. 2022','RAPPEL22') and  pn.usr1 not in ('12-DAS','13-DIDO','19-GIOTTO','19-GIOTTO BE-BÈ','10-ADIGRAF','27-OMYACOLOR','28-PONGO', '18-FILA', '36-TRATTO','48 - LYRA')))/
(select sum(pn.etiliquido) from pn where pn.no in (select no from cl where cl.vendedor = 3) and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-12-31 00:00:00.000') AND PN.REF NOT IN ('DESC. FINANCEIRO','PORTES','DESP.BANCARIAS','COL. COM.','VENDA VIAT CI','RESP.TRANSPORTE','RECIGLAGEM','MARK. CONT. 2013','RAPPEL13','JUROS','VENDA VIAT SI','CREDITO SRCM','RAPPEL14','FEIRAS','MARK. CONT. 2014','MARK. CONT. 2015','RAPPEL15','RAPPEL16','MARK. CONT. 2016','RAPPEL17','MARK. CONT. 2017','RAPPEL18','MARK. CONT. 2018','RAPPEL19','MARK. CONT. 2019','MARK. CONT. 2020','RAPPEL20','MARK. CONT. 2021','RAPPEL21','MARK. CONT. 2022','RAPPEL22') and  pn.usr1 not in ('12-DAS','13-DIDO','19-GIOTTO','19-GIOTTO BE-BÈ','10-ADIGRAF','27-OMYACOLOR','28-PONGO', '18-FILA', '36-TRATTO','48 - LYRA')))*100,2),0) as Perc_dif

from
(
select
pn.no as Num,
(select nome from cl where cl.no=pn.no) as Cliente,
(select zona from cl where cl.no=pn.no) as Zona,
sum(pn.etiliquido) as Valor_1,
0 as Valor_2,
(select vendnm from cl where cl.no=pn.no) as Vendnm
from pn
where  (pn.usr1 not like '%'+'Portes'+'%') 
and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-12-31 00:00:00.000') 
and pn.ref<>''  
and  pn.usr1 not in ('12-DAS','13-DIDO','19-GIOTTO','19-GIOTTO BE-BÈ','10-ADIGRAF','27-OMYACOLOR','28-PONGO', '18-FILA', '36-TRATTO','48 - LYRA')
and pn.REF not IN ('DESC. FINANCEIRO','PORTES','DESP.BANCARIAS','COL. COM.','VENDA VIAT CI','RESP.TRANSPORTE','RECIGLAGEM','MARK. CONT. 2013','RAPPEL13','JUROS','VENDA VIAT SI','CREDITO SRCM','RAPPEL14','FEIRAS','MARK. CONT. 2014','MARK. CONT. 2015','RAPPEL15','RAPPEL16','MARK. CONT. 2016','RAPPEL17','MARK. CONT. 2017','RAPPEL18','MARK. CONT. 2018','RAPPEL19','MARK. CONT. 2019','MARK. CONT. 2020','RAPPEL20','MARK. CONT. 2021','RAPPEL21','MARK. CONT. 2022','RAPPEL22')
group by pn.no

union all

select 
pn.no as Num,
(select nome from cl where cl.no=pn.no) as Cliente,
(select zona from cl where cl.no=pn.no) as Zona,
0 as Valor_1,
sum(pn.etiliquido) as Valor_2,
(select vendnm from cl where cl.no=pn.no) as Vendnm
from pn
where  (pn.usr1 not like '%'+'Portes'+'%') 
and (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-12-31 00:00:00.000')
and  pn.usr1 not in ('12-DAS','13-DIDO','19-GIOTTO','19-GIOTTO BE-BÈ','10-ADIGRAF','27-OMYACOLOR','28-PONGO', '18-FILA', '36-TRATTO','48 - LYRA')
and pn.ref<>''
and pn.REF not IN ('DESC. FINANCEIRO','PORTES','DESP.BANCARIAS','COL. COM.','VENDA VIAT CI','RESP.TRANSPORTE','RECIGLAGEM','MARK. CONT. 2013','RAPPEL13','JUROS','VENDA VIAT SI','CREDITO SRCM','RAPPEL14','FEIRAS','MARK. CONT. 2014','MARK. CONT. 2015','RAPPEL15','RAPPEL16','MARK. CONT. 2016','RAPPEL17','MARK. CONT. 2017','RAPPEL18','MARK. CONT. 2018','RAPPEL19','MARK. CONT. 2019','MARK. CONT. 2020','RAPPEL20','MARK. CONT. 2021','RAPPEL21','MARK. CONT. 2022','RAPPEL22')
group by pn.no
)
x
where x.Vendnm like '%rocha%'
group by x.Num,x.Zona,x.Cliente,x.Vendnm
order by Valor_2 desc
```

Comment: EXISTS is looking for a subquery. The documentation is quite clear on this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 But you could use a where clause here pretty easily. I would suggest you to use ANSI-92 style join syntax instead of this antiquated style. Also, the leading wildcard in your predicate is going to be slow.

Comment: @SeanLange -- EXISTS is only looking for a subquery IF there is more than a single argument (which there is) correct?

Comment: select * from ft, pn  ... is essentially a CROSS JOIN.   At least use an explicit JOIN.

Comment: @Zak no. EXISTS is a logical operator which needs a subquery. Check out the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ft.* 
from ft
join pn on pn.fno = ft.fno
where ft.vendnm like '%rocha%
```

Comment: Not sure why the DV.  It was my first thought as well

Comment: The OP was not asking about a alternative solution ..  OP was asking specifically about EXISTS. *"And I'm not getting what's wrong with this"*

Comment: @Sergey The code you provided works when isolated. But when I insert it in the middle of the whole code it stops working and returns the same error...

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you provide the whole code, because code in my answer is de-facto your code from the question, only rewritten in the correct way

Comment: @Sergey there, added it to the original question

Comment: @Sergey What i need to happen is that the results returned by the rest of the code respect the line you provided